How do I work with the result of model.predict in yolov8 with a webcam?
I have my webcam set up to be the input for my model.predict() function and want to trigger some code if the function detects a certain object. The model.predict() function does not seem to ever terminate when using a webcam however, making this not possible. Just wondering what a solution to this could be. For example, let's say I want the execute another code when it sees a person. is it even possible?
I've tried the Ultralytics class counter but I can't get an output until I end the webcam.

Try this example taken from the YOLOv8 documentation and adapted to your question.
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO
import math

# Load the YOLOv8 model
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")

# Open the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Loop through the video frames
while True:
    # Read a frame from the video
    success, frame = cap.read()

    if success:
        # Run YOLOv8 inference on the frame
        results = model(frame, stream=True)

        for r in results:
            boxes = r.boxes
            for box in boxes:
                confidence = math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100
                cls = int(box.cls[0])
                if cls == 0 and confidence > 0.5:   #0 is the class for person of the pretrained model
                    print("Yay, found a person!")

        # Display the annotated frame
        cv2.imshow("YOLOv8 Inference", frame)

        # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        # Break the loop in case of failure
        break

# Release the video capture object and close the display window
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

